# Move point from a hook in EMMS playlist doesn't work

Tags: hooks, motion, point, emms

I want to move point with the current played song in an EMMS playlist. I tried it with this code:

```lisp
(defun tvd-emms-follow-playing-song()
  (interactive)
  (message (format "%s" emms-playlist-selected-marker))
  (when emms-playlist-selected-marker
    (goto-char emms-playlist-selected-marker)))

(add-hook 'emms-playlist-selection-changed-hook 'tvd-emms-follow-playing-song 1)
```

Now when I press `n` inside a playlist (or any other command skipping a song), the function gets executed and it prints the new position.

However, it doesn't move point.

I also tried another variant:

```lisp
  (defun tvd-emms-follow-playing-song()
    (interactive)
    (let ((track (emms-track-get (emms-playlist-current-selected-track) 'name))
          (oldpos (point))
          (pos 0))
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-buffer)
        (search-forward track)
        (setq pos (point)))
      (message (format "old: %d, new: %d" oldpos pos))
      (goto-char pos)))
```

When I go to the next song, it prints the correct old and new point, but doesn't move point as well.